# FlinkSQL can not register a dynamic nested schema

Tags: apache-flink

description: 
  when I received a kafka message, it's data appearance as follows :

```
{
"name":"xiaoming",
"skill":[{"language1":"java"},{"language2":"scala"}]
}
```

So how can i define the nested schema for field whose name is "skill" that i can use flinksql like follows:

```
select skill.language1 from tableName
```

The following code annotations are available for reference

```
tableEnv.connect
(
  newKafka().version("0.11").topic("clicks")
 .property("zookeeper.connect", "localhost")
 .property("group.id", "click- group")
 .startFromEarliest())
 .withFormat(new Json().jsonSchema("{...}").failOnMissingField(false)
)
.withSchema(new Schema()
       .field("user-name", "VARCHAR").from("u_name")
       .field("count", "DECIMAL")
       .field("proc-time", "TIMESTAMP").proctime())
.inAppendMode()
.registerSource("MyTable")
```

Comment: Please don't post your email for users to follow up with. Stack Overflow wants answers to be on the site itself.

Comment: ok, i'll remember it

Comment: You're much more likely to get answers if you format your code a little nicer. Specifically looking at the final code block, It's not very readable :)

Comment: Fortunately, i  have solved the problem by myself